# How to install Android 6.0 If the device is not listed yet?

Tags: installation, huawei, 6.0-marshmallow, huawei-honor-7

I am interested in installing **Android 6.0** on my device **Huawei Honor 7 (PLK-L01)**.

At this point in time, the device name is not listed in the Android website as a supported device. Would i still be able to install it?

I am really interested to understand the reasons why a certain Android-based device can't support the latest version of Android OS.

Thank you for reading my questions. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry unable to link as my cell is playing up but please see honor 6 International Facebook page... Your device is amongst devices to receive updates starting February 2016. Beta test invites are on in India.

Comment: Always include your phone model in question title so that it's easily searchable by others.. BTW,  Honor 7 will eventually get 6.0 update.. Until then, you either wait, or try the beta ROM if any (as said by @beeshyams) or any custom ROM based on 6.0 if there's any.